# Using Screens with a PHP Script

Tags: linux, php, ssh, bash, gnu-screen

I found an external developer to make me a PHP script to 'snipe' Mineraft usernames.

In order for it to operate, I have to start the script from the command line using this:

```
php -f sniper.php > results.html
```

It works perfectly, but I need to have multiple instances of it running. I came to the conclusion that I needed to use something called 'Screen'. So what I'm looking for is **one** command that can do the following:

- Create a new screen which will automatically navigate to /home/sniper/ and then run the command `php -f sniper.php > results.html`
- Automatically kills the screen upon the PHP script terminating/ending.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer probably lies with the "nohup" command.
Or you can simply add an ampersand (&) at the end of your command to send it to the background and maintain control of the CLI if your script takes a long time. which is why I guess you want to use Screen?

[Ampersands on the command line](http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html)

Comment: So the command to use would be: php -f sniper.php > results.html &

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/sniper
screen -S NameOfScreen -d -m 'php -f sniper.php > results.html'
```

You would need to execute the script yourself the desired amount of times with `bash script`